# Ajax.BeginForm() does not hit the Controller

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having some issue with below code. I have 2 fields and one search button. when I give value only for the field `Holiday` and search, it doesn't hit the controller. But if I give value for the field `Year`, then only it does hit the controller and passes value of both the field to it.

Index.cshtml:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", "Holiday", new System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.AjaxOptions
       {
           InsertionMode = System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.InsertionMode.Replace,
           HttpMethod = "POST",
           UpdateTargetId = "holidaylist"
       }))
{                          
    <table>                                
        <tr>                                    
            <td>Holiday: </td>
            <td><input id="searchtext" name="searchtext" type="text" /></td>                           
            <td>Year: </td>
            <td><input id="year" name="year" type="text" />                                                                  </td>                                                                                      
            <td><input type="submit" value="View" id="BtnSubmit" /></td>
        </tr>                            
    </table>                     
}
```

Controller:

```
 HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Search(string searchtext, int year)
 {            
     try
     {
         string selyear = year.ToString();
```

Comment: What is the name of your controller? Also do you have any custom routes?

Comment: Because parameter `year` is typeof `int` and is required (your controller would be throwing an exception. Change it to `int? year` (nullable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This route is always expecting a year, because year is not an optional parameter.
You can solve this by making year nullable:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Search(string searchtext, int? year)
    {            
        try
        {
            if (year != null) //you will need to handle the case where year = null
            {
                string selyear = year.ToString();
```